# Passing useState state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I extract the **useState** from the file. It is necessary to export exactly **sliderCount** for further work. Thanks in advance.

There are 2 files. The first file uses the **useState** function and changes the state when the button is clicked. In the second file, I want to get the changed state of **useState** from the first file and continue to work with it.

Make conditions, etc., for example:

```
if(sliderCount == 1){
    console.log('Number 1')
}

if(sliderCount == 2){
    console.log('Number 2')
}
```

First file:

```
import React, {useState} from "react";

function ContainerAtwSwap() {
    const [sliderCount, setSliderCount] = useState(0)
    return (
        <div className="container_button__swap-main">
            <div className="dropdown">
                <div className="dropdown-content">
                    <button className="button__swap-button" onClick={() => setSliderCount(1)}>№1</button>
                    <button className="button__swap-button" onClick={() => setSliderCount(2)}> №2</button>
                    <button className="button__swap-button" onClick={() => setSliderCount(3)}>№3</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default ContainerAtwSwap
```

Second file:

```
import React from 'react';

function WorkingEnvironment() {
    ..here I wanted to make conditions, etc.
    return (
        <div className='boxControl scroll' id='boxSliderOne'>
            <div className='container-slider'>
                {}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default WorkingEnvironment;
```

Comment: I think you are looking for useContext https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext

Answer (score 2):

That is what the Context API is for: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Of course you could also use Redux, or transfer data from child to parent and to another child, but the Context API solves this in a much easier way and it is built in without any extra dependency.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to have a parent (of both components) relay the change to the other. Component A will send a changed event to the parent (via a component property event). Then the parent will simply send that changed value to Component B (via a component property).

Comment: Could you show this with an example?

Comment: @Walmery https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html

Answer (score 0):

Grouping your components in one parent component and lifting the state up to their parent is the only way you can share their state.
Otherwise you have to implement a redux store or anything like that.

I link you the React doc's below

https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Comment: Or with functional components like this example
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/what-is-lifting-state-up-in-react/